# What did Java programmers do before Java 8 if they wanted to pass a function around?

Tags: java, lambda, programming-languages

Please be gentle with me.

I hear Java 8 introduced lambdas. But before that, if you wanted to pass around a function, say, as an argument, what did you do?

One way I can think of is to create a single method interface like so:

```
public interface ISingleMethodInterface
{
  bool Really(int n);
}

public bool GimmeFunction(ISingleMethodInterface interface, int n)
{
  return interface.Really(n);
}
```

But that is a very limited application of functions as first class citizens because:

1. You cannot do much other than to execute that function or to pass that object around to another method. With lambdas, you can compose. For e.g. you can negate that lambda like so:

   ```
   public bool GimmeLambdaAndIWillComputeItsInverse(Func<int, bool> predicate, int n)
   {
     return !predicate(n);
   }
   ```
2. You cannot return lambdas or their derivatives. I mean, you can only return that same object like so:

   ```
   // I know Java doesn't have Tuples but let's forget that for now
   public Tuple GimmeFunction(ISingleMethodInterface interface, int n)
   {
     return new Tuple { Item1 = interface, Item2 = n };
   }
   ```

   With lambdas, you can return derivatives like so:

   ```
   public Func<int, bool> GetInverseFunction(Func<int, bool> predicate, int n)
   {
     return n => !predicate(n);
   }
   ```

So, what did you do if you needed to do anything like this?

Comment: Exactly what you describe, command objects. If you had to nest them for the composability, so be it.

Comment: That's too sad. Poor you! :-)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If you'd like to put that down as an answer, I can mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simply passed instances of functional interfaces. Your denigration of this relative to lambdas is a little off because in Java, lambdas are literally functional interfaces. So since one is implemented in terms of the other, they are neither stronger than the other. The difference is in how the source readability strikes you.

Comment: Thank you. I was stating things matter-of-factly. I wasn't really being facetious about it.

Answer (score 1):

Back in ye olden times before Java 8, we had to use the clunky old [anonymous class syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#syntax-of-anonymous-classes) for this sort of thing, leading to code that looked something like this:

```
object.gimmeFunction(new SingleMethodInterface(){
    @Override public bool really(int n){
        return n=="really".hashCode();
    }
});
```

Because this pattern was so common (see [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html)), it was decided that the language could use a much cleaner syntax for it, and so in Java 8 we were given [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to turn the nasty block above into:

```
object.gimmeFunction(n->n=="really".hashCode());
```

Thus helping preserve the sanity of Java programmers everywhere. The two are functionally equivalent, but the first is more flexible, while the second is much, *much* nicer to look at.

Comment: But untrue. We didn't have to use this. It was one of a number of possibilities,